# How can I make a checkbox with a Width & Height of 16px?

Tags: html, css

I want to have a large checkbox with a width of `16px` and a height of `16px`. I don't want to have to use a JavaScript plugin. Can this be done with modern CSS?

Comment: Pure CSS: `input[type=checkbox] { width: 16px; height: 16px }`

Answer (score 17):

You can disable default checkbox appearance with **appearance** property in css and after that style it any way you like with borders, background-images and etc:

```
-webkit-appearance: none; 
-moz-appearance: none; 
-o-appearance: none;
```

To style hover and checked statuses use: :hover, :checked and :hover:checked pseudoclasses.

Another way is to use *transform* property to enlarge it:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(1.6,1.6);
-moz-transform: scale(1.6,1.6);
-o-transform: scale(1.6,1.6);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yup.

http://www.wufoo.com/2011/06/13/custom-radio-buttons-and-checkboxes/

http://www.thecssninja.com/css/custom-inputs-using-css

Comment: The first link is specifically for Wufoo forms.  And  it should be noted that some browsers (Explorer less than 9) will not be able to utilize the techniques in your second link.

Comment: I assumed we can't use the words modern CSS and IE together :) and wufoo still produces HTML including checkbox elements so the technique applies regardless.

Comment: Just thought I'd point it out if it wasn't obvious to anyone.