# Laravel checkbox size

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How can I make the checkbox bigger in size with twitter bootstrap ?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label  class="col-md-8 control-label">{{ Form::label('K_Stenge_Prosedyre', 'Slukke lys, stenge dusj/dører, låse dør til tribune:') }} </label>
    <div class="col-md-3" >
      {{ Form::checkbox('K_Stenge_Prosedyre', 1, array('class' => 'form-control' )) }}  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856748/how-can-i-make-a-checkbox-with-a-width-height-of-16px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkbox() method of the FormBuilder class accepts the following values:

```
string  $name
mixed   $value
bool    $checked
array   $options
```

So, you need to edit your code as follows to assign the 'form-control' class:

```
{{ Fome::checkbox('K_Stenge_Prosedyre', 1, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Within the $options array, you can specify multiple classes or attributes. That said, you'll probably want to assign a custom class to your checkbox and manipulate it using CSS 3 as suggested in the link above.